# Django filter statement error- invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: django

I have 2 tables. I wanted to filter records from the second table based on filtered value from the first table. There is something wrong in my second filter statement. If anyone can help me to sort it out?

> report_table_data=report_table.objects.filter(cn_number=Master_table_data.cn_number))

My codes are as below.

Models.py

```
class Master_table(models.Model):
    sl_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cn_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)

class report_table( models.Model ):
    cn_number = models.ForeignKey(Master_table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remarks = models.CharField( max_length=20, null=False )
```

Views.py

```
def any_view(request):
    Master_table_data=Master_table.objects.get(sl_no=request.GET['key'])
    report_table_data=report_table.objects.filter(cn_number=Master_table_data.cn_number))
```

This throws below error.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'USS2000203'

Answer (score 0):

When you set a model field to `models.ForeignKey()`, the Django dynamic API considers it a reference to that entire object, not the primary key. So a more appropriate name for "cn_number" as a foreign key might be "master_table". Then you can filter by a foreign model field using the format `model_name__field_name=field_value`.

So, for the report_table model:

```
master_table = models.ForeignKey(Master_table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And for the filter function:

```
report_table_data = report_table.objects.filter(master_table__cn_number=Master_table_data.cn_number))
```

Comment: Sorry I was made basic mistake in models.py ( ie., in "reports_table"). I corrected and Iam able to meet my requirements. I have answered my question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I realized later that, I made mistake in my "report_table".
I changed the codes as below and it is working.

***models.py***

```
class Master_table(models.Model):
    sl_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cn_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)

class report_table( models.Model ):
    # I corrected below field name from "cn_number" to "sl_no"
    sl_no = models.ForeignKey(Master_table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remarks = models.CharField( max_length=20, null=False )
```

***views.py***

```
def any_view(request):
    Master_table_data=Master_table.objects.get(sl_no=request.GET['key'])
    report_table_data=report_table.objects.filter(sl_no=request.GET['key'])
```